# Add multiple contact name in opportunity custom field

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to copy all contact name which are in opportunitycontactrole,right now, My current trigger is copying only primary campaign name, I want to copy all contact name in one custom field on opportunity(name__c).

This all name should concatenate and separated by coma in one filed. How can i do that? any idea?

```
trigger PrimaryContact on Opportunity (before update) {

   for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {



       OpportunityContactRole ContactRole =
            [SELECT ContactID from OpportunityContactRole where IsPrimary = True and OpportunityId = :o.id]; 
       Contact c =
            [SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE ID = :ContactRole.ContactID];
       o.name__c = c.Name;
        o.Email__c = c.Email;


     }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward: leverage relationship queries to get the OCRs, `String.join` to do the concatenation, and Trigger.new to do the update without DML.

```
 ...
 for (Opportunity o : [select id, (select contact.name from OpportunityContactRoles) 
                          from Opportunity where id IN :Trigger.new]) {
    String[] contactNames = new List<String>();
    for (OpportunityContactRole ocr : o.opportunityContactRoles)
        contactNames.add(ocr.contact.name);
    o.contactNames__c = String.join(contactNames,',');

}
// Since we're operating on trigger.new, the update is implicit. No DML required
```